# What does Ango Sakaguchi's ability "Discourse on Decadence" do?

Tags: bungou-stray-dogs

In *Bungou Stray Dogs*, Ango Sakaguchi's ability is "Discourse on Decadence".

I googled and looked at the wikis, but there's no information about it.

What does it do?

Comment: IIRC we are only given the name of Ango's ability, Discourse on Decadence. I'll have to check but I'm pretty sure the answer is We don't know yet. Maybe someone who has read the Light Novels can give more details.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Almost all the characters are based off real-life authors, and their abilities are named based on the names of works they wrote, but the connections to the actual abilities is tenuous. So this is not exactly a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

It was revealed in the manga that

> Ango's ability is to read memories that are left in things, basically a memory extraction ability.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.